# Resize iframes with screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I am trying to add only the top functionality block(top brownish coloured block) in  - https://opendsa-server.cs.vt.edu/OpenDSA/Books/Everything/html/Write.html#recurWriteStepsCON in my web page

But the problem is when I am opening in a smaller screen device the iframe is not adjusting and the content inside the iframe is getting cuttoff. How do I adjust the iframe?
I am using

```
<iframe src="https://opendsa-server.cs.vt.edu/OpenDSA/Books/Everything/html/Write.html#recurWriteStepsCON" width="100%" height="330px" scrolling="no" style="border:0;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `width` and `height` of the window of the `iframe`, you can use

```
document.body.scrollWidth
document.body.scrollHeight
```

Full example of code.

HTML

```
<iframe src="https://opendsa-server.cs.vt.edu/OpenDSA/Books/Everything/html/Write.html#recurWriteStepsCON" width="100%" height="330px" scrolling="no" style="border:0;"></iframe>
```

JS

```
function resizeIFrameToFitContent(iFrame) {
    iFrame.width  = document.body.scrollWidth;
    iFrame.height = document.body.scrollHeight;
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
    var iFrame = document.querySelector( 'iframe' );
    resizeIFrameToFitContent( iFrame );
} );
```

Comment: I only want the first box in https://opendsa-server.cs.vt.edu/OpenDSA/Books/Everything/html/Write.html#recurWriteStepsCON

Comment: The above code is giving me the entire document inside iframe

Comment: You didn't say in the question that you want the first box only to take the full screen.

Comment: I had mentioned "this functionality block"

Comment: It is not clear that it means the first block.